# Which one is correct "à qui parlent-ils les touristes" or "à qui les touristes parlent-ils"?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, questions

I am asking the question form of this sentence -

> *Les touristes parlent au guide.*

where we have to ask who the tourists talk to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second one is correct:

> À qui les touristes parlent-ils ?

The second is fine with a comma :

> À qui parlent-ils, les touristes ?

There is a third, simpler option:

> À qui parlent les touristes ?

Comment: The fourth one is frequent but informal: *Ils parlent à qui, les touristes?*

Comment: @NinoFiliu Indeed, also *C'est à qui qu'il parlent, les touristes ?* and even *C'est à qui que les touristes y'parlent*... It's good for a French language learner to be aware of these forms but they are to be used carefully in homeworks ;-)

Comment: Is there anyone of these which are applicable only while speaking i.e with intonation?

Comment: The three ones in comments are informal / colloquial spoken French only but the fact *à qui* is used still makes clear all of them are interrogatives.

Comment: Merci beaucoup! You just saved my grade.